# Help identify small flat wire in glass tube

Tags: identification

Can someone identify this electrical component we found in a Little Doctor LD-250U Ultrasonic Nebuliser.

Seems to be a flat metal wire going through a glass tube.

It is broken and the metals got separated.

The whole thing is just over a centimeter.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like a magnetic reed switch.  More circuit details should allow us to determine if it is normally open or normally closed.

Comment: Is there a magnet nearby - either to prove something is in position or on a rotating shaft?

Comment: You may (@vir) be able to push it back together to see if it's NC or NO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a [reed capsule](https://standexelectronics.com/viewer/pdfjs/web/viewer.php?file=https%3A%2F%2Fstandexelectronics.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F05%2FMK23_V02.pdf) (aka "reed switch") a switch which closes when a magnet is nearby). Replacements can be purchased inexpensively from online retailers- probably something that is similar in physical size will work.

[image]

It may be to detect the presence of the inhalation chamber but I'm not sure of the way these things work. Something like a float with a magnet in it is also possible. I suspect it will be obvious to you upon inspection.

Answer (score 13):

It is a [reed switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch). It's a switch that closes in the presence of a magnetic field. If you look, you'll find a magnet nearby.

You can buy a replacement here: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/magnetic-reed-switches/193

[image: Reed switch]

{Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch#/media/File:Reed_switch_(aka).jpg)}